# facing issue with updating state in reactjs for a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Hi all i am trying to update the state in the functional component which is basically a string, when i enter the text in the input element like 'abc' the state is updating till 'ab' and when i enter 'abcd' the state is 'abc' can anyone please help me out in solving the issue.

code:

```
const [searchDetails, setsearchDetails] = useState('')
const onChangeSearch = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
setsearchDetails(e.target.value)
console.log(searchDetails)
dispatch(onSearchById(searchDetails))
if (e.target.value.length == 0) {
    dispatch(onSearchById(''))
}
```

}

```
<InputBase inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search users' }} onChange={onChangeSearch} />
```

Answer (score 1):

A short and sweet input with mutable data could look like

```
   <InputBase value={searchDetails} onChange={(e) => setSearchDetails(e)}/>
```

We set the value of the input with the initial state, typically an empty string and then whenever the input has changed we just immediately update the state from inside the input